# opening docusign envelope for signature is showing custom fields

Tags: docusignapi, signing

Review and sign document is displaying custom fields to add in the document instead it should just allow me to sign the document and prefill the custom fields as configured in docusign portal.

[docusign document displaying custom field during signing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lUAgy.png)

This is leading to free form signing. which is displaying the custom fields. it should not display the custom fields instead allow me to sign the signer

Answer (score 0):

You need to add at least one field (tab) for each signer. Otherwise (as is happening to you), the signer will be given the palette of fields (free form signing).

Solution: add a `Sign here` field where you want the signer to sign.